# jquery checkbox disable/uncheck

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I have 2 checkboxes as below. The 2nd one should be clickable only if the 1st one checked. This I managed to do.

But if the first one is unchecked, the second one should be disabled and unchecked as well.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var ckbox = $('#optin');

  $('input').on('click', function() {
    if (ckbox.is(':checked')) {
      $('#tc').removeAttr('disabled'); //enable input

    } else {
      $('#tc').prop('checked', false); //remove check
      $('#tc').removeAttr('checked'); //disable input

    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="optin" id="optin" class="required">
<label for="optin"> Checkbox1 </label>

<input type="checkbox" name="tc" id="tc" class="" disabled="disabled">
<label for="tc"> Checkbox2  </label>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd do it like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input').on('click', function() {
    $('#tc').prop({
      'checked': $('#optin').is(':checked'),
      'disabled': !$('#optin').is(':checked')
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="optin" id="optin" class="required">
<label for="optin"> Checkbox1 </label>

<input type="checkbox" name="tc" id="tc" class="" disabled="disabled">
<label for="tc"> Checkbox2  </label>
```

Comment: It should be possible to only check checkbox1

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by that. Do you mean like https://jsfiddle.net/q01p2gf1/?

Answer (score 0):

In the `else` you're trying to remove the checked attribute. Instead set the disabled property to true.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var ckbox = $('#optin');

  $('input').on('click', function() {
    if (ckbox.is(':checked')) {
      $('#tc').removeAttr('disabled'); //enable input

    } else {
      $('#tc').prop('checked', false); //remove check
      $('#tc').prop('disabled', true); //disable input

    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="optin" id="optin" class="required">
<label for="optin"> Checkbox1 </label>

<input type="checkbox" name="tc" id="tc" class="" disabled="disabled">
<label for="tc"> Checkbox2  </label>
```